Correct CORS configuration for minio
I have minio running locally, and I face cors issue while fetching a file. So I try to run this config:
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
  <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
  <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
  <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

I run command:

mc cors set myminio/mybucket cors.xml

But it gives me error:

mc:  Unable to set bucket CORS configuration for
myminio/mybucket. A header you provided implies functionality that is
not implemented.

How to set it correctly to get rid of CORS issue?
Edit:
This is the exact error when accessing resource in minio bucket:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What "CORS issue"? Please quote error messages verbatim.

I have updated post with error message.
